# Как сделать замену значений ячеек по значениям ячеек другого столбца?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Необходимо сделать замены в столбце B по значениям ячеек в столбце A в тех же строках. Есть ли в гугл-таблицах какие-то встроенные функции для такого?

Comment: нашёл на английском stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/google-spreadsheet-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell-value

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не соответствует тематике ресурса

Answer (score 0):

В Ячейке "B1" пишешь =A1. После меняй значение "A1", а значение "B1" поменяется согласно формуле. За уголок протяни ячейку "B1" вниз и получи подряд автозаполнение "=A1","=A2"..."A1000".